# Is Ubuntu 14.04 installed?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I've been trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8, on my HP Pavillion g6-2320.
The installation got complete the first time, but Windows got booted. I tried installing again, but got errors,

> grub-efi amd64-signed failed to install into /target/
>
> grub-install /dev/sda failed

during different combinations of enabling/disabling Secure Boot/ Legacy Mode

I installed reFind Bootloader but still it didn't work.
Now I used BootRepair, and I got reFind , with options for Windows and Ubuntu. But after using Windows once, now Windows gets booted by default - no reFind. I can still access reFind from BootOptions but now both its options load Windows 8. I can access Ubuntu by choosing the option from BootOptions. How to display grub/reFind screen on system startup ?

But in all cases where I'm accessing Ubuntu, the option "install release" is present. So is Ubuntu really installed in my system ?
[image: Ubuntu with install release option]

I'm okay even with a solution requiring a reinstall of Ubuntu if other methods are hard. But do give me any advice on partitioning or Legacy/Secure boot, which would help me install Ubuntu without using bootrepair.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a 'boot' partition while installing Ubuntu so that `grub` may be installed in it. Otherwise, although Ubuntu may be installed, you will not be able to boot into it.

For instructions, refer to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still facing issues.
On doing boot-repair after making a boot partition, I was asked to type the following commands
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda4" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda4" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda4" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed linux-signed*
And then
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda4" apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed linux-signed-generic

But boot-repair gives error messages. Please look into this https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6gOLcu-YXR5WElzY3FtVUR0RUE&usp=sharing